# Creating Ftp txt file in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am running a batch script and trying to create a txt file with the file information.  Below is what I have written.  The PROJECT_PATH AND REMOTE_FTP_OUTPUT_PATH can change depending on what is assigned to the variable in the script.  I am getting errors.  Here is the part of the script to create the file:

```
    echo **** PROJECT PATH IS *** %PROJECT_PATH%
    echo **** directory location is ***** dir

    REM ***** Creat ftp.txt dynamically *********************************

    echo open clientftp.accuweather.com > !PROJECT_PATH!\ftp.txt
    echo user>> %PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt
    echo accubot >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt
    echo HpD7f1sTymq2 >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt
    echo cd download\mobile_builds\android\v3 >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt
    echo if not exist %REMOTE_FTP_OUTPUT_PATH% mkdir %REMOTE_FTP_OUTPUT_PATH%  >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt
    echo cd download\mobile_builds\android\v3\%REMOTE_FTP_OUTPUT_PATH% >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt 
    echo put %APK_FULL_OUTPUT% >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt

echo quit >>%PROJECT_PATH%\ftp.txt
```

and here is my output when I run for those lines:

```
    **** PROJECT PATH IS *** temp_builds\6228-10.06
**** directory location is ***** dir
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error opening script file temp_builds\6228-10.06\ftp.txt.

Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.

FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuffer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]

  -v              Suppresses display of remote server responses.
  -n              Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.
  -i              Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file
                  transfers.
  -d              Enables debugging.
  -g              Disables filename globbing (see GLOB command).
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
  -a              Use any local interface when binding data connection.
  -A              login as anonymous.
  -x:send sockbuf Overrides the default SO_SNDBUF size of 8192.
  -r:recv sockbuf Overrides the default SO_RCVBUF size of 8192.
  -b:async count  Overrides the default async count of 3
  -w:windowsize   Overrides the default transfer buffer size of 65535.
  host            Specifies the host name or IP address of the remote
                  host to connect to.

Notes:
  - mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit.
  - Use Control-C to abort commands.
```

Comment: You are using a relative path. If your current active directory is not correct, it is possible that the folder where you try to create the file does not exist

Comment: I did/do realize that I am using relative...what doesn't make sense is I had our IT department clone a server that runs automated builds so that I could update to handle building with Gradle as opposed to Ant.  On the working build server, the relative paths are good, but on this new one, they are not.  If I put in absolute paths, then all is good...but why?  hmmmm

Comment: A relative path is correct IF the current active directory is correct. You can not explicitly set the current active folder in your code but then the process that launches your code should ensure the active folder is what it should.